# Message: Error: remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, terminal, github-desktop

When I'm trying to do a commit in my repository, I see this error in the editor "git Error: remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021." I'm using vscode right now, but i'm capable to do nothing with git, github desktop or github cli.

I generate a new tocken in my github account, but always appears the same message. Somebody can help me? Thank you.

Comment: Git made it mandatory to use authentication tokens. Log into your account and read https://github.com/settings/tokens and https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/other-authentication-methods#basic-authentication for instructions to set them up.

Comment: You might have to clear the credentials stored in your credentials manager, because they'll be reused without prompting you. On my Windows machine, that's in the Windows Credential Manager. If you're on a different OS it'll be something else. Once cleared, you should get prompted for your PAT the next time you try to connect.

Comment: @CoderApprentice Note that it's Git*Hub*, not Git, that does this.

Comment: @torek Woopsie you're right. I guess to me Github is the embodiment of Git.

Answer (score 1):

First logout then go to github settings and generate a new token. Vs code will then ask you for token when you pull/push your code.